# PuTTY or OTHER - Keep executing command even after exiting PuTTY

Tags: linux, command-line, putty, process, gnu-screen

I have a couple of commands that I need to run. These commands needs to continually run even after I exit my interface. When I have access to the Linux GUI, I execute something like:

```
cd /home/testuser/Scripts*
xterm -hold -T "Background_Script1" -e  "service1-start.sh" &
sleep 10
xterm -hold -T "Background_Script2" -e "service2-start.sh" &
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicates questions:
http://superuser.com/questions/581963/how-can-i-use-nohup-if-the-shell-script-taking-more-time-to-run
http://superuser.com/questions/644537/bash-processes-reattach-process-started-in-background
http://superuser.com/questions/488434/running-linux-commands-in-the-background-ampersand-or-screen

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not running these services as daemons?

Comment: Are the commands meant to be services that should run at near-100% uptime "forever", or a long-running processing task that's expected to finish after some time? All answers will "work" for both cases, but the proper recommendation will be different.

Comment: Which specific distribution of Linux are you using? I found that running `set -m;` makes it so that my scripts continue running after I log out on CentOS and RHEL.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try

> nohup Background_ScriptX &

nohup ensures that a process is not terminated when a terminal is closed. The & symbol pushes the process into the background.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: nohup definitely does the job

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: _screen_ has one clear advantage over _nohup_: _nohup_ does not allow you to return to a running command (e.g. next morning to read its stdout, then choose to kill it, etc).  _screen_ allows you to do exactly that.

Comment: nohup sends the output to a file where it can be processed.

Comment: For those who are new to `nohup`, it's basically "no hangup" - with nohup, the hangup (`HUP`) signal is ignored.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to read the output at a later date, you can use `screen`:

```
screen -d -m my_command
```

This gives you a detached terminal you can connect to later (`screen -r`) to read the stdout/stderr output.

Comment: +1. For one, if you close your terminal (e.g. putty) and then you open it again and reattach to screen (`screen -r`) you will also have all the output your program produced and you'd have otherwise "missed". Plus, screen can do so many amazing things, like split screens, etc.! :)

Answer (score 5):

Another option if `nohup` command is not available is to use the [disown](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/) command.

First you can view your background tasks by running `jobs` in terminal. You can get the job number from there.

Now just run `disown %[job number]` and the process will be detached from the current terminal and stay alive when you log out.

Side note: Make sure that you are asking the correct question. If you are running actual services as you hint in your sample you might want to look into how to create a daemon in the OS of your choice. This is to make sure that the process still runs after a reboot and make it more consistent with other services.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since `screen` has been mentioned: there are other terminal multiplexers out there.  I like `tmux` very much, see e.g. this other superuser question, [tmux vs screen](https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen) for a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:    `setsid`
Setsid also works to background programs and allows them to keep running after the terminal/ssh session is disconnected.

Use it like this:

```
setsid program-to-background
```

Manpage: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html